# Progress bar not working on button click C# windows application

Tags: c#, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I want to synchronize my local and web database so i have written a stored procedure using linked server. My stored procedure executes fine and data synchronization is successful but the procedure takes around 7-10 minutes to get executed. The exact timing cannot be determined. So whenever the procedure runs on my windows application then the page seems as if it has become unresponsive though the process is still going on. 
So i am having a "Data Sync" button on my page on click of which i want the progress bar to display the progress of the stored procedure. For the time being I am taking the average of last few execution timings to define the time duration for which the stored procedure runs. Now the problem is that when i click on the data sync button then the progress bar doesn't work. Kindly help me with this issue.

My code is as follows:-

```
namespace RMS
{
    public partial class DataSync : Form
    {
        connection con = new connection();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    static int rowCount;
    static int syncTime;
    static int timeSlice;

    public DataSync()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDataSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // Start the asynchronous operation.
           backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

        try
        {

            con.GetConnectLive();
            con.GetConnect();

            if (con.CnLive.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection to Live Server Successful!!!...Data Synchronisation may take several minutes so do not cancel the operation while in execution mode");

                btnDataSync.Enabled = false;
               btnDataSync.Text = "Please Wait...";

                string Str = "RMS_LocalToLive";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(Str, con.Cn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;

                rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                if (rowCount > -1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Total no. of rows synchronised = " + rowCount);
                    btnDataSync.Text = "Success";
                }
                else
                {
                   MessageBox.Show("Data Synchronisation couldn't be completed because of connection problem... Please try again!!!");
                }

            }
            else
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to Live Server...Please check your internet connection and try again!!!");
            }


            con.GetDisConnect();
            con.GetDisConnectLive();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Please check your internet connection and try again!!!");
        }

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            con.GetConnect();

            string Str = "RMS_DataSyncTime";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(Str, con.Cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;

            syncTime = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

            timeSlice = syncTime / 100;

            con.GetDisConnect();


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve last Data Synchronisation Timing");
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= synctime; i=i+timeslice)
        {

        Thread.Sleep(timeslice);  
        // Report progress.
         backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }


    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        // Set the text.
        this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "% Completed";
    }

    private void DataSync_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgse)
    {

    }
}
```

}

Comment: I do not undrstand what you do here. When you first run the code your backgroundworker is supposed to do and then do a for-statement in which you report a progress in each iteration the progress does not display the actual progress of your task, it does the task and afterwards simulates a progress that in fact is just a imaginary progress inside the part of your code that is supposed to report progress, is that really what you want to achieve or do you want to progress the progress of the actual task that is already finished before you start your progress reporting ?

Comment: I want to simultaneously show the progress of progress bar when the stored procedure is executing in the background...The progress bar should show 100% when the stored procedure gets executed completely...Kindly rectify my code and paste the new code...

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that, while you are executing your progress bar updates in the `BackgroundWorker`'s thread, the `ReportProgress()` updates never make it to the UI thread, because you've blocked that thread with the main SQL operation.

Instead of doing that, you should do something more like this:

```
private void btnDataSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start the asynchronous operation.
    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

    btnDataSync.Enabled = false;
    btnDataSync.Text = "Please Wait...";

    bool success = false;

    try
    {
        // Execute the query asynchronously
        success = await Task.Run(() => ExecuteLocalToLive());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Please check your internet connection and try again!!!");
    }

    btnDataSync.Enabled = true;
    btnDataSync.Text = success ? "Success" : "Failure";
}

private bool ExecuteLocalToLive()
{
    bool success = false;

    con.GetConnectLive();
    con.GetConnect();

    if (con.CnLive.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection to Live Server Successful!!!...Data Synchronisation may take several minutes so do not cancel the operation while in execution mode");

        string Str = "RMS_LocalToLive";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(Str, con.Cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 1200;

        rowCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (rowCount > -1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Total no. of rows synchronised = " + rowCount);
            success = true;
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Data Synchronisation couldn't be completed because of connection problem... Please try again!!!");
        }
    }
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to Live Server...Please check your internet connection and try again!!!");
    }

    con.GetDisConnect();
    con.GetDisConnectLive();

    return success;
}
```

I have rearranged the code that handles the button state and text, so that it's still executed in the UI thread where it belongs, even though the method itself is not. You also never appeared to set the button back to the enabled state; it's not clear to me whether that was intentional or not, so I went ahead and added a line to do that.

Finally, I will strongly recommend you figure out a better way to report status to the user than the calls to `MessageBox.Show()` you have now. The biggest issue is that you don't even start doing any work until after the user dismisses the initial message, which immediately puts your progress bar out of sync with the actual work. But it's also better to keep all your UI in the UI thread, and to keep UI separate from non-UI logic (i.e. the SQL operation).